# Deleting a row using data grid view from access database in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb, delete-row

I have a code as follows:

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtGrdViewOgr.SelectedRows)
        {
            dtGrdViewOgr.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
        }
```

The code works well when it comes to removing a row from the data grid view however it doesn't delete its real databases row. To do that I either have to save the edited data grid view or write a command that is aimed at the database. I don't know exactly what to use here can you help me out. I'm using Data.OleDB

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

For mssql standart security connection string:

```
constr = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);  
    OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand();
    delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    con.Open();
    delcmd.Connection = con;
    delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Comment: Hmm i'm getting a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" error at the line:
oDBCom.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblOgrBil WHERE ID=" + dtGrdViewOgr.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: try  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() instead dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() -- > if your data id is first cell of row.

Comment: I actually tried that before coming up with my own solution, sadly it gave the exact same error.
Also I should add, why did you add the last `+ ""` part?

Comment: Yes, this part should be deleted. Which event do you use for this ? DatagridviewChangeIndex, Click Etc.?

Comment: i use button.click

Comment: Add control your datagridview selected or not. if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value =! null) {your function here } etc.